# Waiting until a lock is acquired in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to solve a concurrency problem while getting a lock, the code looks like this:

The real lock is acquired as soon as the thread starts, which is already too late.

```
acquireLockAndRunOnNewThread(() -> {
    acquiredLock=true;
    continueWithOtherStuff();
}

//do not continue until the lock is acquired
while(acquiredLock==false){
    Thread.sleep(100); 
}
continueWithOtherStuffThatAlsoAcquiresALockAtSomePointInTime()
```

How can I solve this problem properly without thread.sleep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

Then:

```
acquireLockAndRunOnNewThread(() -> {
    latch.countDown();
    continueWithOtherStuff();
}

//do not continue until the latch has counted down to zero.
latch.await();
continueWithOtherStuffThatAlsoAcquiresALockAtSomePointInTime()
```